# Evenly Choosing 'X' items from 'Y' Collections of 'Z' Size

Tags: math, loops

I'm creating a display interface of lets say 'products'.  For this example lets say the display will show at max 4 products.  There are a variable number of sources that the products can came from.  The number of sources will never be larger than the number of products to display (at most 4 sources for this example).  Each source contains 1 or more products.  The goal is to evenly distribute the number of products displayed across the sources.

The logic for 4 products would be handled as follows.

- If there is **1 source**, then 4 items will be selected from that source.
  ***(4x1)***
- If there are **4 sources**, then 1 item will be selected from each
  source. ***(1x1+1x1+1x1+1x1)***
- If there are **2 sources**, then 2 items will be selected from each
  source ***(2x1+2x1)***, unless one source only has 1 product, then it will follow as ***(1x1+3x1)***
- If there are **3 sources**, then 1 item will be selected from 2
  sources and 2 items will be selected from 1 source ***(2x1+1x1+1x1)***

Before I start looping to output products, I have a collection of sources and the count of items in each source.

My question is:

> What is the simplest way to loop through each source and output the
>   appropriate amount of products?

Keep in mind that each source may only have 1 product, so it is possible that 4 products cannot be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple Python code to select the products.

It works by looping over the sources and adding one product at a time.

This should result in a fair distribution between the sources.

The code could be made much more efficient if you find it is too slow.

```
Z=[1,10,10]       # Number of products available for each source
Y=len(Z)          # Number of sources
X=4               # number of products to output
B=[0]*Y           # Number of products to select for each source

a=0               # Next source to try and take a product from
while sum(B)<min(sum(Z),X):
    a=(a+1)%Y     # Change to a different source for the next product
    if B[a]<Z[a]: # Check that this source still has products left
        B[a]+=1   # Note that we have taken a product from source a

print B
```

In this example it prints

```
[1, 2, 1]
```

to signify taking 1 product from the first source, 2 from the second, and 1 from the third.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a program sample written in C#, which outputs as a proof the sources identified by ID, the number of products available in each source and the selected products (with the source ID attached to each of them):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Product
    {
        public int Ordinal { get; set; }
        public Source Source { get; set; }
        public Product(int ordinal)
        {
            Ordinal = ordinal;
        }
    }
    class Source : List<Product>
    {
        public int Id { get { return this.GetHashCode(); } }
        public int AvailableProducts { get { return this.Count; } }
        public Source(int availableProducts)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < availableProducts; i++)
            {
                var p = new Product(i);
                p.Source = this;
                this.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }

    class Sources : List<Source>
    {
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sources = new Sources();
            var productsToBeSelected = 4;
            var sourceNumber = Math.Min(productsToBeSelected, 4);
            var maxProductsPerSource = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i < sourceNumber; i++)
            {
                var source = new Source((new Random(i + Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Length - 6)))).Next(maxProductsPerSource));
                sources.Add(source);
            }

            var candidateProducts=new List<Product>();
            sources.ForEach(i=>i.ForEach(p=>candidateProducts.Add(p)));

            var selectedProducts = candidateProducts.OrderBy(i => i.Ordinal).Take(productsToBeSelected);

            foreach (var item in sources)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source ID: {0}, {1} products",item.Id, item.Count);
            }

            foreach (var item in selectedProducts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Product ordinal: {0} from source {1}", item.Ordinal , item.Source.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```